# I dont see any Provisioning Profile on my code sign part of configuration XCODE 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I Have a strange problem in my xCode, im the par of code signing i dont see any profile and even more i dont get the small arrows 
[image: xCode signing part]

in keychain i have my things you can see it in the picture

[image: Keychain]

In my Organizer i see my profile but in xcode in the code signing section i got stacked with an old profile and dont see any other, and dont have the little arrows that allow to choose profile

[image]

i have draged and import my profile to my device and restarted xCode and no luck i m adding the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the new profile using organizer. You need to import the Profile to your project also. you can do it from

> Organizers > Devices > Library section > Provisioning Profiles >
>   Import (at the bottom)

Now they will appear in your project code signing.

Comment: I have done it and added the pic to the question and still nothing, what do you think?

Comment: You should paste the Provision Profils tab from Library section.

Comment: I have done it and the result is that i see that i have this profiles in my iphone but still cant see in in code signing section

Answer (score 1):

The last image you provide are the provisioning profiles for the device you have plugged in. Select "Provisioning Profiles" under the "Library" section and drag the profile into the main window there. Should solve your problem.

Comment: I have done it and added the pic to the question and still nothing, what do you think?