# I don't see the small arrows on the right side of the params where I should choose values

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I don't see the small arrows on the right side of the params where I should choose values.

[image]

The same problem published in
[Strange Xcode signing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069562/strange-xcode-signing-issue),
[I dont see any Provisioning Profile on my code sign part of configuration XCODE 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053921/i-dont-see-any-provisioning-profile-on-my-code-sign-part-of-configuration-xcode)

I ran into this problem right after setting Code Signing Identity's value to something like "iPhone Developer: Fedor Shihantsov (FG32Q65DF)".
May it be that some symbols in this string caused this issue?

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I uninstalled, downloaded and installed XCode again.
The same problem persists. :(

Comment: The same problem occurs with a new project. However, there is no issue under another account on this Mac.